# Div Background of content placeholder in asp.net changes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, asp.net

I'm using div to wrap content placeholder in masterpage of asp.net web app.

```
<div id="bg" class=""> 
                <!-- Main Content Placeholder -->
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                <!-- Main Content Placeholder -->
</div>
```

CSS is :

```
<style>
            #bg{
                background-image: url('/imgs/smartcity-c.jpg'); 
                background-size: cover; 
                background-repeat: no-repeat; 
                background-attachment: scroll;
            }
 </style>
```

I'm using checkbox and jQuery to change background of div :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#toggleButton").change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $("#bg").css("background-image", "url(/imgs/smartcity-lb.jpg)");
            } else {
                $("#bg").css("background-image", "url(/imgs/smartcity-c.jpg)");
            }
        });
    });
```

but whenever I go to content pages its background changes back to default one. Of course it reloads and sets according to CSS. but is there any way to keep last changed element permanent, so for all content page background remains same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `localStorage` value on `$("#toggleButton").change`. When page load check  `localStorage` value an according to that set background image.

Example:

```
$("#toggleButton").change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $("#bg").css("background-image", "url(/imgs/smartcity-lb.jpg)");
    window.localStorage.setItem("bg","A");
  } else {
    $("#bg").css("background-image", "url(/imgs/smartcity-c.jpg)");
    window.localStorage.setItem("bg","B");
  }
});
```

On page load inside `document.ready` check for localStorage.

```
if ("bg" in localStorage) {
  if (window.localStorage.getItem('bg') == "A") {
    $("#bg").css("background-image", "url(/imgs/smartcity-lb.jpg)");

  } else {
    $("#bg").css("background-image", "url(/imgs/smartcity-c.jpg)");
  }

} else {
  $("#bg").css("background-image", "url(/imgs/smartcity-lb.jpg)"); // in case localStorage is not set
}
```